# How do i deny access to admin page in Django 3.0?

Tags: python, django

I want it so that when a non staff/non admin/non superuser tries to access the django admin page, it raises a 404 error and when a user is staff/admin/superuser it directs them to the admin page.

```
def nonstaffuser(view_func):
  def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        raise Http404
return wrapper_func
```

This is the decorator I made.

```
urlpatterns = [  path('admin/', nonstaffuser(admin.site.urls)) ]
```

I imported the decorator and it does raise a 404 when a user isn't staff but when a user is actually a staff/admin/superuser it raises a error: 'tuple' object is not callable. How do I fix this? Thank You

Comment: _"when a user is staff/admin/superuser it directs to the login for the admin page"_: What do you mean by this? You can only know if a user is staff/admin/superuser if the user is already logged in. Why do you direct them to the login page, again?

Comment: oh yeah I didn't think about that. I'm new to django so sorry. I plan on using a {% user.is_superuser  %} in my html to list a way to the admin site without having to type in the url. But yeah thats what I want: if user isn't staff/admin/superuser it raises 404 and when they are, direct them to the site.

Comment: Please include the stacktrace of the actual error.

Comment: decorators.py in wrapper_func, line 17. Line 17 is "return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)". It says "TypeError at /admin/".